# Does anyone know what brand of Bicycle this is?

Tags: identify-this-bike, badge

I’ve been doing some research but can’t seem to find this logo anywhere.

[image: head badge remains]

[image: overview]

Comment: Yeah, it's there now.  Twice.  But an image of the entire bike from the side would be helpful.

Comment: And I'll note that the logo has been sanded away.

Comment: I bought this bike and it was very beat up. And someone had spray painted it all sorts of ugly colors. I took it apart, sanded it down and painted it myself. I sanded the logo because it was very badly painted.

Comment: @DanielRHicks yeah - looks like the entire bike has been repainted too - can see the cyan and black bleeding into each other, and just above the logo-plate can see something darker - could be navy blue.

Comment: @LuisCaraveo do you have any photos of it before sanding ?

Comment: Yes, but I can’t load it. It’s too large of an image. It didn’t have any markings or stickers. No serial numbers either. Just that front logo to go by.

Comment: Serial numbers are useless for ID.   Looks like a "K"  to me but the only headtube badges I can find are Kinesis and Kink, and neither look anything like this.

Comment: Thank you! I’ll look into those as well.